# Custom keyboard shortcuts in KDE don't work correctly after setting them in terminal

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I'm trying to make a script that switches shortcuts controlling the audio player between Spotify and foobar2000. The command below successfully modifies the configuration file, but the shortcut change doesn't get applied until I restart the KDE session. How can I force KDE to apply the change? Restarting Plasma doesn't help.

KDE version is 5.21.2.

```
kwriteconfig5 --file khotkeysrc \
              --group Data_4_1Actions0 \
              --key CommandURL \
              'env WINEPREFIX="~/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix ~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\ Menu/Programs/foobar2000.lnk /playpause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running `qdbus org.kde.keyboard /modules/khotkeys reread_configuration` afterwards.

Comment: Please don't forget to check back and accept your own answer to lift it up the Unanswered -queue.